# How to match PageView height to items Height?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to use `PageView` in Flutter application to display bank cards.

The problem is that height of `PageView`'s page is something like `match_parent` and fills almost whole screen, but I would like to match `Card`'s height inside `PageView` - something like `wrap_content` in android's XML layouts.

`Card` view contains:

- `Text`- alias
- `CardView` - card graphic

Both are placed in `Column` widget which is placed in `Container`.
`Text` and `CardView` are with Blue background, `Container` is with Green background.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
            child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text(card.alias))),
        Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1.586, child: CardView(card: card))),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: App layout preview]

And here is first problem. I am using `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to wrap `Column` height but it is not working, so Green color is filling screen - but should be same height as Blue color.

Because single page is that high, so PageView is also too high.

`PageView` is created with that code and `PageView` has Red background.:

```dart
Widget buildPageView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<WalletCard>> cards) {
  return PageView.builder(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 7 / 8),
      itemCount: cards.data == null ? 0 : cards.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Item(index: index, card: cards.data[index]);
      });
}
```

and that method (`buildPageView`) is used to provide `Widget` inside `CardsPageView`. `CardsPageView` is placed on screen with this code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: CardsPageView(walletCards: cardViewModel.walletCards),
              )),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.orange,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text('PAY'),
          ),
        ],
      ));
}
```

Comment: have you try to wrap your container with height: double.infinity